# Best way to create an Xmpp connection and passing the Instance without Re-creation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xmpp, xmppframework

I have class called `XmppChatManager` which have all the necessary methods like `initializingConnection()` and `sendOneToOneMessage()`, other classes that need to use this class need to do something like this:

> > XmppChatManager xmppchatmanager = new XmppChatManager(this, userId, password);

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(){
                        public void run(){
                            try {
                                xmppchatmanager.initializingConnection();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (SmackException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    thread.start();
                }
            });
```

> This is pretty much all I need to get started, the issue i'm having is when I try calling the sendOneToOneMessage() method from the chatClass, I have to get the instance of the created connection because `Smack Error` will occur if I try reconnecting when the connection is already initiated! So I need to make available the instance of that initiated connection by creating a method called `getInstance()` I guess this might be simple but I have tried but I'm not getting it. Any one with better way of handling such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your xmppchatmanager be singleton,for example

```
public class XmppChatManager{
   static class Loader{
        static XmppChatManager sInstance = new XmppChatManaget();
   }

   public static XmppChatManager getInstance(){
        return Loader.sInstance;
   }
}
```